# How to make an object appear different to the poster in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project that will allow people to create groups then send a *task* to all of the people who are apart of that group. When the person who matches the same user_id as the value attached to the task, I would like it for the task to appear different (different text on it and some other stuff) and when you click it, it shows analytics for that task. I just need to know what it takes for me to pull of altered versions of an object for the person who posted it. Thanks for any help. I may be too vague here, I'm still very new to Rails.

Comment: post the relationships

Answer (score 2):

If a task belongs to a user, and you have access to current_user (if you're using devise it's built in, w/ bcrypt you'll have to write yourself), an easy way to do this in the views would be to say something like:

```
<% if task.user_id == current_user.id %>
   <-- stuff you want to show the assigned user -->
<% else %>
   <-- stuff you want to show everyone else -->
<% end %>
```

Assuming you're using erb. But you get the gist.